# MediaElement.js 2.3.2 not working with Safari 5.1.1 on Win 7 64-bit

Tags: mediaelement.js

When testing MediaElement.js in the version of Safari I have: 5.1.1 (7534.51.22) on Windows 7  Professional 64-bit, the video player fails to load, leaving me only the option to download the video. My user agent is:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22

This is true for the demo I downloaded (v 2.3.2), http://mediaelementjs.com and the application I'm trying to use MediaElement.js for. Has anyone else experienced this? And does anyone else have any idea why that might be? Or what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: 20 minutes later I've worked it out - for HTML 5 video on Safari you need to have QuickTime installed. What a brilliant decision by Apple in implementing web standards!

Hope this might help a few other people.